# Boolean evaluation in a lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Just tooling around for my own amusement, and I want to use a lambda, because I feel like it. Can I replace this function with a lambda?

```
def isodd(number):
    if (number%2 == 0):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Elementary, yes. But I'm interested to know...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

And if you don't really need a function you can replace it even without a lambda. :)

```
(number % 2 != 0)
```

by itself is an expression that evaluates to True or False. Or even plainer,

```
bool(number % 2)
```

which you can simplify like so:

```
if number % 2:
    print "Odd!"
else:
    print "Even!"
```

But if that's readable or not is probably in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: See, this was the heart of the matter. I was under the impression that both 0 and 1 are True in Python, since they are both ints.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html -- "The following values are considered false: ... zero of any numeric type, for example, 0"

Comment: I'd still stick it in a function. With modulo 2 I always need a second or two to figure out whether it evaluates true for even or for odd. if isodd(number) is clearer. Little details like this tend to add up to make a real difference.

Comment: @SilentW: You might have been thinking of Ruby. The only "false" values there are nil and false.

Comment: @Alexander: Please lose the parentheses in your `if` statement.

Comment: @John Machin: Sure. I added them to make the idea more clear but you're right, they bug me too.

Answer (score 12):

```
lambda num: num % 2 != 0
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can:

```
isodd = lambda x: x % 2 != 0
```

Answer (score 10):

Others already gave you replies that cover your particular case. In general, however, when you actually *need* an `if`-statement, you can use the conditional expression. For example, if you'd have to return strings `"False"` and `"True"` rather than boolean values, you could do this:

```
lambda num: "False" if num%2==0 else "True"
```

The [definition](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) of this expression in Python language reference is as follows:

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates `C` (not `x`); if `C` is true, `x` is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and its value is returned.

Answer (score 7):

And also don't forget that you can emulate complex conditional sentences with simple short-circuit logic, taking advantage that "and" and "or" return some of their ellements (the last one evaluated)... for example, in this case, supposing you'd want to return something different than True or False

```
lambda x: x%2 and "Odd" or "Even"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
isodd = lambda number: number %2 != 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`isodd = lambda number: (False, True)[number & 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Any time you see yourself writing:

```
if (some condition):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

you should replace it with a single line:

```
return (some condition)
```

Your function then becomes:

```
def isodd(number):
    return number % 2 != 0
```

You should be able to see how to get from there to the lambda solution that others have provided.

Comment: Any time you see yourself writing `if (some condition):` or `return (some condition)`, lose the parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  But I thought the example read better, given that `some condition` is not valid syntax.  Maybe I should have used square brackets.