# What does `map(lambda s: s != None, some_list)` mean?

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to understand the Deep Q-learning algorithm for standard Cart-pole example using [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html), and in def optimize_model() method, I don't understand whether the lambda expression returns a boolean or an index:

```
non_final_mask = torch.tensor(tuple(map(lambda s: s is not None, batch.next_state)), device=device, dtype=torch.bool)
```

where `batch.next_state` is just a list, and `s` is defined only in this line.

Judging from the documentation and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168236/boolean-evaluation-in-a-lambda), `lambda s: s is not None` produces a boolean. However, when I simply type in python:

```
>>> lambda s: s is None
```

I get

```
<function <lambda> at 0x100997010>
```

If I indeed get a boolean from aforementioned lambda expression, how does the `map()` method handels it as a first argument?

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: Thank you very much for all your comments and thorough answers! I need a little time to chew it all, but I disagree with [duplicate] mark, as I haven't seen anywhere how boolean function have been applied to a list with `map()`. It is still not that clear to me.

Comment: A function is an object. If you want to *call* it, you need to add parentheses and provide the argument. `map` does this calling for you.

Comment: `my_totally_cool_lambda = lambda s: s is None`   .... `my_totally_cool_lambda ("Hi")` .... `my_totally_cool_lambda (None)`

Comment: map is well documented - it takes a function as 1st and an iterable as 2nd parameter - `lambda s: s is not None` defines a function using 1 param and returning True or False.   --> [how-are-lambdas-useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/how-are-lambdas-useful)

Comment: @Patrick Artner Thanks! OK, then lambda indeed in this case indeed returns a boolean. But then sorry, I couldn't find how map() handles booleans as 1st parameter, and this is why I posted this question.

Comment: @trincot Thanks! So, does map() essentially performs this operation: `(lambda s: s != None)(batch.next_state)` ?

Comment: `map` *doesn't* take a Boolean as 1st parameter. It takes a function, and *uses* that function on values in its 2nd argument to produce values to yield.

Comment: @RuslanMukhamadiarov, `batch.next_state` is an iterable, and *each* member of that iterable is used for a distinct call of the lambda function. `map` returns an iterator over those results, from which your code builds a tuple.

Comment: "Judging from the documentation and this example, lambda s: s is not None produces a boolean." **When it is called**, yes. Just like how if you defined a function with `def` and then tried to check the value of **the function**, you would see [a function, and not the result of calling it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933). The point of `map` is that it calls the function that you give to it, repeatedly - please see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel thank you very much for your detailed comment! I, however, would disagree with you on your desicion to mark this question as a duplicate. I do understand now better how `map()` works, but I still don't quite understand what do I get from applying a function which returns boolean on a list. This is why I asked this question. Just a set of booleans of `len(batch.next_state)` size?

Comment: "but I still don't quite understand what do I get from applying a function which returns boolean on a list.... Just a set of booleans of len(batch.next_state) size?" Yes. There isn't any more to explain or to understand. And it's clear from the explanations given in the duplicate. The purpose of `map`, as explained there, is to apply the function repeatedly to the input sequence, and collect the results. If you have a sequence of values and your function returns a boolean when applied to one of the values, that results in a sequence of booleans. It really is that simple.

Comment: map applies any function to any iterable and returns the result as iterable. The kind of function is not fixed, yours returns a boolean, others may return a string. f.e.  `c = lambda chopper: f"chopped {chopper}"` ... `fruit = ["apple", "pear", "plum"]` ... `result = list(map(c, fruit))` ... `print(result)` => `['chopped apple', 'chopped pear', 'chopped plum']`

Comment: @Patrick Artner thank you for your reply! I think I understood the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is a type, but to a first approximation you could assume it is a function defined as

```
def map(f, xs):
    for x in xs:
        yield f(x)
```

To a second approximation, it can take *multiple* iterable arguments. In this form, it "zips" iterables together using its function argument, rather than just yielding tuples.

```
def map(f, *args):
    for t in zip(*args):
        yield f(*t)
```

In your example, the function is being supplied as a lambda expression, rather than a function defined using a `def` statement.

```
non_final_mask = torch.tensor(tuple(map(lambda s: s is not None, batch.next_state)), device=device, dtype=torch.bool)
```

is equivalent to

```
def not_none(s):
    return s is not None

non_final_mask = torch.tensor(tuple(map(not_none, batch.next_state)), device=device, dtype=torch.bool)
```

In either case, `map` yields a series of Boolean values created by applying a function to each element yielded by the iterable `batch.next_state`; those Booleans are used to create a `tuple` that's passed to `torch.tensor` as its first argument.

---

Note that `map` *was* a function in Python 2, and it returned a list.

```
$ python2
[some macOS blather deleted]
Python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 25 2021, 03:11:28)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc- on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> map(lambda s: s is not None, [1, None, 'c', None])
[True, False, True, False]
```

In Python 3, it was made a type so that it could return a lazy iterable instead. (The function is only applied as you iterate over the instance of `map`, not immediately upon calling `map`.) Had no `map` function already existed, it's not likely Python 3 would have added it (or at least, it would only be available via the `itertools` module, rather than as a built-in type). `map` can virtually always be replaced with a generator expression. For example,

```
non_final_mask = torch.tensor(
   tuple(s is not None for s in batch.next_state),
   device=device,
   dtype=torch.bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not only about a `lambda` expression, it's also about the `map` function.
Lambda is just a function and can return any type actually.

```py
is_x_none_lambda = lambda x: x is None # Funtion is declared AND assigned

def is_x_none_function(x)->bool:
    return x is None

some_other_name = is_x_none_function

# In REPL if you don't invoke them:
is_x_none_function # <function is_x_none_function at 0x7f81b467ab60>
is_x_none_lambda # <function <lambda> at 0x7f81b467aac0>

a = None
b = "String, not a None..."

# The return type of both of them is hovever "bool" indeed
# Again in REPL if you invoke any of the above:
is_x_none_function(a) # True
is_x_none_lambda(a) # True

is_x_none_function(b) # False
is_x_none_lambda(b) # False

# map
test_data = [None, 5, "test str"]
# All the calls below do the same
tuple(map(is_x_none_function, test_data))
tuple(map(some_other_name, test_data)) 
tuple(map(lambda x: x is None, test_data))
tuple(map(is_x_none_lambda, test_data)) 
# Take function which I provide (which can be a function assigned to a variable OR a lambda) and "lazily" invoke it on each element of the "test_data"
# The "tuple" is needed as well, cause without it, you'd get <map object at 0x7f81b4643190>
```

Side notes:

- instead of `tuple` it could be e.g. `list` to convert from `map` to a data structure
- `map` built in docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map
- this is completely subjective, but stuff from functional programming like `map`, `reduce` and so on can most often be replaced with comprehension of some type, which is imho way more readable
  e.g.

```py
# Instead of
tuple(map(x_is_none_lambda, test_data))
# one can do:
tuple([x_is_none_lambda(item) for item in test_data])
# and if operating on lists instead of:
list(map(x_is_none_lambda, test_data))
# this
[x_is_none_lambda(item) for item in test_data]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I do appreciate your effort, and I agree with you that using this `tuple([x_is_none_lambda(item) for item in test_data])` expression would make code more readable.